# How to use powershell support for Build Events in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2019, build-events

I found this link [Add powershell support for Build Events](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-powershell-support-for-build-events/507512) indicating that as of VS2019 v16.2 you can now use powershell directly in VS build events.  Mads closed this with the following comment:

> This feature has now been released in the latest product update
> released version 16.2. Please install and let us know your feedback.
> Please continue to provide feedback and help us be even better.

I'd like to use this but I can't find it in VS and I can't find docs on it (there is a lot of noise on this topic).  Mads comment above was dated Jul 18, 2019 so it's been there a while.

Have I missed or misunderstood something about that thread?  Does anyone know how this feature might be enabled/used?
*I'm specifically interested in this feature **not** in generic info on running powershell as a build event via cmd.*

**Update**: I've added the following ticket [Add (or document) powershell support for Build Events](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-or-document-powershell-support-for/1535591?entry=myfeedback&space=8&preview2=true) to the MS Developer Community site to request support or documentation of this feature.

Comment: That was around the same time that the Developer PowerShell prompt came out so I'm betting that they closed the thread thinking that answer the question.  It doesn't look like any additional powershell support has be introduced to pre/post build events.  You can still use the work-around of calling `powershell.exe pre/post_script.ps1` as the event  and put all your build logic in the PS script.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Daniel - there doesn't appear to be an option to "turn on powershell" for build events instead of using CMD.